# como recorrer un array con varios objetos mismas propiedades

Tags: javascript, array

hola tengo un array con varios objetos mismas propiedades sobre este array necesito sumar todos los precios de la citas pero tengo un problema ya que en algunos objetos el valor o precio de la cita esta en null y he probado algunos funciones pero no terminan de sumar ya que por el null no suman correctamente quisiera saber como **SUMAR EL TOTAL DE TODAS LAS CITAS** hacer esto correctamnete ademas quisiera filtrar la **CANTIDAD DE CITAS POR MESES** osea que me diga cuantas citas hay en enero cuantas en febrero etc ya que tengo la propiedad fecha
el array mas o menos esta asi

```
    array citas = [
          {id: 1, precio:null, fecha "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
          {id: 2, precio:21333, fecha "2022-04-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'cardiologia'},
         {id: 3, precio:null, fecha "2022-06-10 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
         {id: 4, precio:30000, fecha "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
         {id: 5, precio:26000, fecha "2022-01-04 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'} ];
```

EstE seria en javascript

```
var PRECIOCITAS   = 0;
    var nrocitas = 0;  

  
citas.forEach( function(cita){
        PRECIOCITAS    += cita.custom_service_price;
        nrocitas += 1; })
        console.log(PRECIOCITAS);
        ///RESULTADO POR CONSOLA
```

**EL PROBLEMA QUE AL SUMAR LA CANTIDAD DE PRECIOS MUCHAS ESTAN EN NULL TEMPORALMENTE Y ME DA ALGO COMO ESTO CON UN CICLO FOReACH:**
PRECIOSCITAS=0566.00nullnull0.00nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull50000.00null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo código con explicación en comentarios.

```js
const citas = [
    {id: 1, precio:null, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
    {id: 2, precio:21333, fecha: "2022-04-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'cardiologia'},
    {id: 3, precio:null, fecha: "2022-06-10 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
    {id: 4, precio:30000, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
    {id: 5, precio:26000, fecha: "2022-01-04 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'}
];

let precioCitas = 0;
const nroCitasPorMes = {}; // diccionario para guardar las citas por mes

citas.forEach(cita => {
    precioCitas += cita.precio ?? 0; // si precio es null establecer en 0
    const mes = new Date(cita.fecha).getMonth() // obtener el número del mes
    // registrar la cita en el diccionario
    nroCitasPorMes[mes] = (nroCitasPorMes[mes] ?? 0) + 1
});

console.log({precioCitas, nroCitasPorMes});
```

Comment: ok que pena ya tendria el array co las citas x mes como asigno esos valores a variables x ejemplo var citasenero =a la propiedad 1 del arreglo y asi con los demas?

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas asegurarte de que el valor es numérico y, en este caso, parece que es entero, por lo que puedes usar [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para "forzar" el valor y, si hubiera error, agregar `|| 0` para que devuelva cero:

```js
let citas = [
    {id: 1, precio:null, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
    {id: 2, precio:21333, fecha: "2022-04-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'cardiologia'},
    {id: 3, precio:null, fecha: "2022-06-10 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
    {id: 4, precio:30000, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
    {id: 5, precio:26000, fecha: "2022-01-04 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'}
];

let precioCitas = 0;
let nroCitas = 0;

citas.forEach(cita => {
    // Forzar entero (null = 0)
    let precio = parseInt(cita.precio) || 0;
    precioCitas += precio;
    nroCitas ++;
});

console.log(precioCitas, nroCitas);
```

Comment: ok amigo y sabes como puedo filtrar x meses la cantidad de citas?

Comment: @eduinfabianardilaruiz, yo crearía un objeto con cada fecha (año/mes) como propiedad y, dependiendo del uso que le vayas a dar, el valor sería un contador o un arreglo con las citas correspondientes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer facilmente uando la funcion `reduce`:

```js
const citas = [
          {id: 1, precio:null, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
          {id: 2, precio:21333, fecha: "2022-04-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'cardiologia'},
         {id: 3, precio:null, fecha: "2022-06-10 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
         {id: 4, precio:30000, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
         {id: 5, precio:26000, fecha: "2022-01-04 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'} ];
         
const sumaPrecios = citas.reduce((acc, cita) => acc + (cita.precio || 0), 0);

const conteoPorMes = citas.reduce((acc, cita) => {
  const mes = cita.fecha.substring(0,7);
  acc[mes] = acc[mes] || 0; //Si el mes no está definido lo defines
  acc[mes]++;  //Sumas uno a ese mes
  return acc;
},{})

console.log("Suma precios: ", sumaPrecios)
console.log("Conteo por mes: ", conteoPorMes)
```